# How to replace text in XWPFRun with jpg image with given size using apache poi with java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a service that replaces the placeholders of some given word document. And I have some properties that give me information about what should be in the placeholder.
I use Apache Poi to set new text to word document.

```
    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphList) {
        for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
            // for example if run has placeholder ${topicData:labelEn}
            // i just set new text for it
            run.setText(properties[placeholder], 0);
        }
    }
```

So replacing text with text is not a problem.
But now i want to add new placeholder **${qr:size}**, which replaces this text with qr image generated by my qr generator function in **XWPFRun**, so my problem is how can I replace text with image using apache poi, so that the top left coordinates of the image start at position **${qr:size}**.

**Please** don't forget that i am not asking about replacing image to image. I already know how to do that. I am interested in replacing text with an image.

Comment: "So replacing text with text is not a problem.": It is a big problem. What if the placeholder `${topicData:labelEn}` is not in one and only text-run in Word? It could be spread over several text-runs. Also it could be in a text-run along with other text. So main problem is to find the one and only text-run to replace. If you have solved that problem, then use [XWPFRun.addPicture](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#addPicture-java.io.InputStream-int-java.lang.String-int-int-) to add the pictute to that run. Then set text in that run empty (`""`).

Comment: yes i tried it works but with 1 little problem the image is positioned 1-2 pixels to the right i think its because of setting $, { and placeholder to -> ""

Comment: So now i want to try delete a run from paragraph, i trield removeRun, but it works with position of the run, but in my case i will not know the position of the run, so someone know how to do it?

Comment: "i think its because...": No, it is not. It is because the picture is inserted as an in-line-with-text picture. This is what `XWPFRun.addPicture` does. Apache POI is not able to insert an anchored picture having text wrapping options. Why not simply replacing a placeholder-pcture which could be an anchored picture having text wrapping options?

Comment: I cant. My team decided to use a text placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void replaceTextWithImage(XWPFRun run, int size) {
    BufferedImage qrCodeImage = printVersionService.generateQRCodeImage("QR TEXT");
    File imageFile = new File("image.jpg");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(qrCodeImage, "jpg", imageFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
        run.addPicture(is, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "QR TEXT", Units.toEMU(size), Units.toEMU(size));
    } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    run.setText("", 0);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).